# Ramda - extract object from array

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to filter an array of objects with Ramda and it is working almost as I planned but I have one small issue. My result is array with one filtered object which is great but I need only object itself not array around it.

My example data set:

```
const principlesArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    harvesterId: "1",
    title: "Principle1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    harvesterId: "2",
    title: "Principle2"
  },
]
```

And that is my Ramda query:

```
R.filter(R.propEq('harvesterId', '1'))(principlesArray)
```

As a result I get array with one filtered element but I need object itself:

```
[{"id":1,"harvesterId":"1","title":"Principle1"}]
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use R.find instead of R.filter, to get the first object found:

```js
const principlesArray = [{"id":1,"harvesterId":"1","title":"Principle1"},{"id":2,"harvesterId":"2","title":"Principle2"}]

const result = R.find(R.propEq('harvesterId', '1'))(principlesArray)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

A more generic approach would be to create a function that takes a predicate used by R.where, pass the partially applied R.where to R.find, and then get the results by applying the function to the array:

```js
const { pipe, where, find, equals } = R

const fn = pipe(where, find)

const principlesArray = [{"id":1,"harvesterId":"1","title":"Principle1"},{"id":2,"harvesterId":"2","title":"Principle2"}]

const result = fn({ harvesterId: equals('1') })(principlesArray)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using find instead filter was so obvious... In my case it should be enough. Thank you :)